# How can I connect to my VPN if Windows won't let me?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I'm trying to connect to our company VPN, but Windows tells me I need an active Internet connection for that. Which I'm pretty sure I have, but it won't let me connect anyway:

[image]

I'd really like to connect to the VPN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try connecting to your VPN from the command line:

```
rasdial "Hartwig VPN" username password
```